What's the purpose using the assignments symbol in if statement?
Most responses indicate the symbol = is used as an assignment operator.
Indeed, this aligns with what I've learned while studying programming.
I encountered this issue when using SonarQube scanning software: CWE-481: Assigning instead of Comparing
As shown above, it's a problem found in an older version of jQuery, and an excerpt reads as follows:

The assignment in this segment is located elsewhere:

What's the purpose of this approach?
Is there always be TRUE conditions? (if I did not misunderstand).
Is this approach for code organization purposes,
does it aid in future maintenance and code readability, or is it simply an error in usage?

"No matter what, it will always be True." are you sure? Can a falsy value not be assigned?

@VLAZ I'm not sure.Please let me know if not true.

@VLAZ yeah agreed. It seems intentional in the while, but I think the if version is a typo. Either way, it's very ambiguous and not clear in intent. It'd fail my code review at least :)

You claimed it's always true. But I can't verify this.

@RoryMcCrossan the if is also correct. If there is a value - assign that value to an object. If the value is falsy - don't assign it.

@RoryMcCrossan Don't think so. If the header is present, it will be assigned to lastModified and evaluate as truthy.

"What's the purpose of this approach?" - Brevity, and feelings of smugness.

Presumably if the response doesn't have that header, the return value (and therefore result of the assignment expression) would be false-y. Otherwise you'd have to do two steps: const lastModified = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"); if (lastModified) { ... }

a problem found in ... jQuery that's their mission statement

To teach me the knowledge.

if (lastMod = somefunc()) { ... is just shorthand for lastMod = somefunc(); if (lastMod) { ....  Most IDEs (eg jsfiddle) will give this as a warning as it looks like an error.  Adding brackets may remove this warning:  if ((lastMode=somefunc())) {.   See MDN "the assignment expression itself has a value", which is why you can do let y; let x = y = 2

@fdomn-m Good morning.Thank you.



function ifAssignment() {
  let a,b,c,d;
  if((a = true)) {
    console.log("a", a);
  }
  if((b = false)) {
    console.log("b", b);
  }
  if((c = "c")) {
    console.log("c", c);
  }
  if((d = "")) {
    console.log("d", d);
  }
}

ifAssignment()



Results show that assignment in if control can be either true or false.

Or another way of putting it, the result of an assignment is what was assigned.  eg. (a = 'hello')  the result is hello,.  Then of course the result of that can be truefy or not.

Thanks to your code complement.It's easy to understand.
